# google closure compiler ignoring source_map_input

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

I have a quite complex build system and I'm trying to create a source map based on specific files. Those files have been concatenated previously and they also have a source map. Now this is the scenario:

Files **a, b, and c** are concatenated into **abc.js**, with **abc.js.map**, then closure-compiled into **ABC.js**, with **ABC.js.map**, using "source_map_input" of **abc.js.map**. Files **d, e, and f** are concatenated into **def.js**, with **def.js.map**, then closure-compiled into **DEF.js**, with **DEF.js.map**, using "source_map_input" of **def.js.map**.

Everything up until now works fine. If I use ABC.js on a website, I can correctly see all the sources of a, b and c.

Now I want to use closure compiler to concat & compile **ABC.js** and **DEF.js**, producing a single output sourcemap and source file **ABCDEF.js** (+.map) using "source_map_input" twice (once for each file of course), providing the source maps **ABC.js.map** and **DEF.js.map**. However, this doesn't seem to work at all. The generated map doesn't point to the original files (a, b, c and d, e, f), but to **ABC.js**.

Is this a bug in closure compiler, or is it simply not possible to provide multiple files with "source_map_input"?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve the issue. The files built by closure compiler don't contain `// #sourceMappingURL=...`. If I add this line to the end of ABC.js and DEF.js, the source map is correctly resolved back to the individual files.

Comment: You can use output_wrapper option to setup source map link